# Решение задачи на основе бинарного поиска по ответу

Tags: java, c++, алгоритм, поиск, бинарный-поиск

Имеется задача:

> На прямой дано N точек и число k. Вы должны покрыть точки с помощью k
> одинаковых по длине отрезков, причем требуется определить, какая
> минимальная длина отрезков подходит в задаче.

Например:

- Если на прямой даны точки `A=10, B=15, C=30, D=40` и `k=2`, то эти точки можно покрыть отрезками длины `10`. Первый отрезок покрывает точки A и B, второй — C и D.
- Если `k=3`, то эти же точки можно покрыть отрезками длины `5`. Первый отрезок покрывает точки A и B, второй — C, третий D.
- При `k=4` ответ будет `0`. Каждый из четырех отрезков покрывает одну из точек.

Для решения задачи используйте двоичный поиск по ответу. Отрезок длины 0 это самое маленькое возможное значение, а отрезок длины от первой точки до последней — самое большое, такой один отрезок гарантированно покроет все точки.

Идею бинарного поиска по ответу я понял, но как применить его к этой задаче не особо понятно, подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать данный алгоритм. По идеи нужно начинать от 0 и увеличивать размер отрезка, но при бинарном поиске происходит наоборот и отрезок уменьшается от максимального к минимальному, и не понятно как это решается.

Ну и не понятно как потом проверять подходит ли длина отрезка, как это реализовать тоже непонятно.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: вот вам идея: начинаете от `отрезок длины от первой точки до последней` и делите пополам, пока можете покрыть все точки.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, а не подскажите еще как проверять возможность покрытия для данной длины отрезка?

Answer (score 3):

Без ограничения общности можно считать, что 1) каждый из К отрезков начинается в одной из точек и 2) отрезки не перекрываются друг с другом

Я надеюсь, что эти утверждения понятны и не требует объяснений? Если нет - просто порисуйте на бумаге, мне это кажется довольно очевидным.

Тогда, следуя рекомендации задачи "использовать двоичный поиск" выбираем длину отрезка.

Теперь - вот он, алгоритм проверки возможности покрытия для данной длинны отрезка:  Начинаем покрывать К такими отрезками все точки: "кладём" первый отезок, начиная его из первой точки. смотрим, сколько точек покрылось. "кладём" второй отрезок из первой точки, не покрытой первым отрезком. В конце -получаем результат, удалось ли покрыть все точки.

Далее нужно сделать шаг алгоритма двоичного поиска - уменьшить длинну отрезка в два раза. Далее - в общем, понятно - про двоичный поиск то Вы писали, что его идея Вам понятна.

Comment: Хорошее объяснение про покрытие. На всякий случай я бы добавил, что при двоичном поиске не обязательно длина отрезка уменьшается в два раза (например, на первом шаге она может вырасти в 1.5 раза) - в два раза сокращается интервал поиска.

Answer (score 3):

Предположим, что точек у нас всегда больше 0, и что они упорядочены. Тогда

Сначала напишем функцию, которая по данным точкам, k и длине отрезка, скажет, можно ли такими отрезками покрыть точки

```
private bool isLenRight(int[] points, int k, int len)
{       
    int end = points[0] + len;
    k--;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {

        if (end < points[i])
        {
            k--;
            end = points[i] + len;
            if (k < 0) return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true; 
}
```

Далее все элементарно, самый обычный двоичный поиск

```
private int getLen(int[] points, int k)
{
    if (k >= points.Length) return 0;
    
    int min = 0; 
    int max = points[points.Length-1] - points[0];
    
    while(min != max)
    {
        int mid = min + (max - min) / 2;
        if (mid == max || mid == min) return max;

        if (isLenRight(points, k, mid)) max = mid;
        else min = mid;
    }
    
    return max; 
}
```

Проверяем

```
Console.WriteLine(getLen(new[] {10, 15, 30, 40}, 2));
Console.WriteLine(getLen(new[] {10, 15, 30, 40}, 3));
Console.WriteLine(getLen(new[] {10, 15, 30, 40}, 4));
```

Вывод

```
10
5
0
```

Comment: Уважаемый tym32167, аплодирую вашему ответу! Спасибо и за качественный ответ, и за высокую планку, который задают Ваши ответы.

Comment: @Андромеда если вам ответ помог, то галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: @tym32167 а если помогло несколько ответов? :)

Comment: > а если помогло несколько ответов? - мне кажется, ответ, который дал tym32167 - более полный. Он содержит код. Мой ответ содержит только слова. Принцип "покажите ваш код!" нарушен :-)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ галка ставится всегда по разумению автора вопроса. Я лишь только напомнил о такой возможности.